# JQuery: How do I use the JQuery delay with my own function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I use the JQuery `delay` in conjunction with my own defined function, pseudo-code like so?:

```
$('#foo').slideUp(300).delay(800).myOwnFunction(1,2,3);
function myOwnFunction (a,b,c) {...}
```

The code above doesn't work, however - per the [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) it appears like it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setTimeout()` here. After the animation has finished sliding up, it will run the anonymous function that wraps the `setTimeout()` which calls your function after approx 800 milliseconds.

```
$('#foo').slideUp(300, function() {

    setTimeout(function() {

       myOwnFunction(1, 2, 3);

    }, 800);

});




function myOwnFunction(a, b, c) {
       alert(a + b + c);
   };
```

It doesn't matter that this was defined below as it's definition should be hoisted to the top.

Comment: Do I have to define myOwnFunction inside setTimeout?

Comment: @Timj Nope sorry, I fixed the example.

Comment: check this article on the settimeout,setiterval will give you more idea

http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#foo')
    .slideUp(300)
    .delay(800)
    .queue(function () {
        myOwnFunction(1,2,3);
        $(this).dequeue();
    });
```

See:

- http://api.jquery.com/queue/
- http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/